# PHP/WEB: How to store hashed passwords

Tags: php, security, hash, sha256

I understand how to hash/salt/etc passwords on a php page. However, I do not know how to actually store those passwords

For instance, if I just need to have a PHP document validate one password against another (that is stored on the server), how do I actually store the password it needs to be validated against? If I just have it sitting in a file, someone could read the source PHP to find that file, read the file, and then send a fake POST with that hashed password. If I have it salted, they just need to read the source code and then remove the salt. Can they see the PHP source?

Hopefully that makes sense. I just need to know how to store hashed/salted passwords on my web server. Can I just put them in a .txt?? What happens if someone reads that .txt, can't they just send a fake POST and the server will accept it??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some reading material : [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't put them in a `.txt` file. At least not one in a web-accessible directory. I would advise storing them in a database.
2. If someone does gain access to your password hashes, they can't use it to login, at least not directly, because you would be re-hashing the hash when verifying the password, thus producing a different, non-matching hash. However, having access to the password hash does make it a lot easier to crack the actual password via dictionary or brute-force, since checking to see if the password is a match can be done locally and does not require making a request to your server. For this reason, be sure to keep the hashes reasonably safe, and if they do get leaked, force password resets on your users.

Incidentally, you don't have to worry about users being able to view your PHP source code, unless they are able to find an exploit in your code that will disclose the source code.